# If $f(x):[1,3]\to [-1,1]$ satisfies $\int_1^3 f(x)dx=0$, then find max value of $\int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I managed to graph a very rough sketch, which involves $f(2)=0$ and the crests peaking at $-1$ and $1$ on either side of $x=2$

Now for maximization, assume $f(x)=1$ in $[1,2)$ and $f(x) = -1$ in $(2,3]$

So $$\int_1^2 \frac{f(x)}{x}dx + \int_2^3 \frac{f(x)}{x}dx$$
$$=\ln 2$$

However this isn’t in the options. Where am I going wrong

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128128/discussion-on-question-by-aditya-if-fx1-3-to-1-1-satisfies-int-13).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ satisfies the condition. Then using $1-f(x)\ge 0$ and $f(x) +1 \ge 0$,

\begin{align}
\int_1^3 \frac{f(x)}{x} dx &=  \int_1^2 \frac 1x dx - \int_1^2 \frac{1-f(x)}{x} dx -\int_2^3 \frac 1x dx + \int_2^3 \frac{f(x) +1}{x}dx\\
&= \ln \frac 43 - \int_1^2 \frac{1-f(x)}{x} dx + \int_2^3 \frac{f(x) +1}{x}dx.\\
& \le \ln \frac 43 -\frac 12 \int_1^2 (1-f(x))dx + \frac 12 \int_2^3 (f(x) + 1) dx\\
&= \ln \frac 43 + \int_1^3 f(x) dx = \ln \frac 43. 
\end{align}

Thus the maximum is really $\ln (4/3)$.

Comment: How did you get that $1-f(x)\ge 0$ inequality? It might be obvious but it’s not striking me

Comment: I just use $f(x)\le 1$.... @Aditya I mean, the particular function that you choose in the post must be the correct one (at least intuitively). That means $1-f(x)$ in $[1,2]$ and $f(x) +1$ in $[2,3]$ must be the "excess".

Comment: And in the third line, why was x replace with 2? Is it to maximise that particular function? Also if we replace x as 2 wouldn’t $f(x)$ also be affected?

Comment: I used that $x\le 2$, so $1/x \ge 1/2$. Then since $1-f(x)\ge 0$, I can multiple it on both side. @Aditya